# Service management using RESTful requests

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, rest

I am currently working on a project where we need to establish communication like an ESB, between a REST API and the apps services on a small scale.

Scenario:

Assume a web app front end (e.g. Django/Python or Ruby/Rails) and services that are accessible via a HTTP RESTful request.

How can I:

- make it configurable which web services are called on a web request depending on the request and not requiring code changes (through keys for example)
- encapsulate or implement the services in a way to make it easy to manage them e.g. start/stop etc.

I have been looking at spring.io, but cant work out whether this could be used for the this??

I am open to all suggestions,

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why I have been voted down? It is a genuine question that will help not only me, but other Stackoverflower's facing the same predicaments

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want an authorisation solution.

In Rails, [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) are very popular. You could also implement it from scratch. Here is a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) to help you get started.

Comment: Really like the look of Cancan. Is there a example diagram anywhere, or could you describe to me where it would sit in the diagram. At the moment I am thinking it would be a filter that sits in behind the REST API? @Peeyush

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the question completely so can provide only limited help! Maybe you could try updating your question with more details and an example or create a new question and link back here. Anyways, the way authorisation generally works is as follows : The user request for something.. let's say a GET request to some URL. The authorisation code determines if the user is authorised to access that resource.. and then if the user is authorised, corresponding actions are done...